# CSS Only - Show Hide an element with hover/unhover action?

Tags: css

I want to show / hide a variable on hover with help of CSS only. Here's my html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>Hover here to see magic</div>
    <div>Hello World</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my css:

```
:root {
  --show-state: none;
  --p-color: black;
}
body {
  padding: 2rem;
}

body > div {
  color: var(--p-color);
  display: var(--show-state);
}

body > p {
  border: 2px solid var(--p-color);
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: var(--p-color);
}

body > p:hover {
  --p-color: blue;
  --show-state: block;
}
```

When I hover to the element, the paragraph color changes however since --show-state sets to block I should be able to see the div but it still remains invisible:

[image]

I have also attached code sandbox to try it on: https://codesandbox.io/s/html-code-editor-forked-hv5teh?file=/style.css:0-251

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong or if this won't be possible at all only via CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the variables for the p element, not for the whole body (or :root) so the div isnt affected.

However, since the div comes after the p element and is its immediate sibling you can use the + combinator to affect the settings of the CSS variables for that div.

```css
:root {
  --show-state: none;
  --p-color: black;
}

body {
  padding: 2rem;
}

body>div {
  color: var(--p-color);
  display: var(--show-state);
}

body>p {
  border: 2px solid var(--p-color);
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: var(--p-color);
}

body>p:hover+div {
  --p-color: blue;
  --show-state: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <p>Hover here to see magic</div>
    <div>Hello World</div>
</body>

</html>
```